# Apache 2 separate auth based on ip

Tags: apache

```
ProxyPreserveHost On

<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

<Location />
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    AuthType basic
    AuthName "Secured Site"
    AuthBasicProvider "google_authenticator"
    Require valid-user
    GoogleAuthUserPath /etc/apache2/ga_auth
    GoogleAuthCookieLife 3600
    GoogleAuthEntryWindow 1
    Allow from 10.0.0.1/24
    Satisfy Any
</Location>
```

So above is my current Apache config. What it is doing is requiring a username and password if not connecting from within my network. The password is a combination of the user password and Google authenticator code smashed together because there is only 1 password field. This works great.

But what I really want it to have this work the same as it currently does from outside my network. But from inside my network I want it to require a password, just the password not the Google authenticator code. In other words, is there a way to have separate location configs based on ip?

By the way, I am using apache as a reverse proxy and nothing else. I am not aware of a way to easily get Google Authenticator setup on NGINX so that is why I am using Apache. If another service would work better than I am all ears! Thanks.